# Query on the basis of empty array and non existing field with other conditions in expr

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I have documents like

```
{
     '_id': ...  
     'registration_temp_perm_no' => 'SIEI/216/2020',
     'first_name' => 'Azra',
     'last_name' => 'Ali'
},
{
     '_id': ...  
     'registration_temp_perm_no': ....
     'first_name': ...,
     'last_name' : ...,
     'transport_details' : [
         {
           ... 
           status : "Inactive"
         }
     ]  
},
{
     '_id': ...  
     'registration_temp_perm_no':...
     'first_name' : ....
     'last_name': .....,
     'transport_details': []
}
```

Note that the documents are created/updated via front end functionalities in the following three ways

1. where embedded document 'transport_details' does not exist at all.
2. where embedded document 'transport_details' contains empty array
3. where embedded document 'transport_details' may contain multiple sub arrays

Now I want to fetch those documents where the status of last sub array  is "Inactive" or "Requested" and where the sub array "transport_details" doesn't exist and "transport_details" is empty.

I have written query like

```
   $query =  array(
             '$or' => array(
                           array("first_name" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                           array("middle_name" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                           array("last_name" => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex($arg, 'i')),
                           array("registration_temp_perm_no" => $arg)
                         ),
                        "schoolId"=>  new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($this->schoolId),
                        '$expr' => [
                           '$or' => [
                              ['transport_details' => ['$exists' => false]],
                            ['transport_details' =>  ['$size' => 0]],

                            ['$eq'=> [['$arrayElemAt' => ['$transport_details.status', -1]], "Requested"]],
                            ['$eq'=> [['$arrayElemAt' => ['$transport_details.status', -1]], "Inactive"]],
                           ]
                        ]
                    );
```

If we remove the lines ['transport_details' => ['$exists' => false]],  ['transport_details' =>  ['$size' => 0]], the query is able to fetch those documents where the status of last sub array is "Inactive" or "Requested" otherwise it does not work.

Comment: $or means at least one of the conditions met. If you need "last sub array is "Inactive" **or** "Requested" **and** where the sub array "transport_details" doesn't exist **or** "transport_details" is empty." it should be `{$and[$or:{}, $or:{}]}` condition.

Comment: could u please provide mongodb command directly

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$expr`, all next operators should have [Aggregation-expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions) syntax. Check full list [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#index-of-expression-operators)

You need to change

```
['transport_details' => ['$exists' => false]], 
['transport_details' => ['$size' => 0]]
```

to

```
['$eq'=> ['$transport_details', undefined]], //equivalent to {$exists:false}
['$eq'=> [['$size' => '$transport_details'], 0]] // $size returns number, we compare numbers
```

If we apply `$IfNull` operator, we combine "no exist" + "empty array" into single condition.

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
  ... your extra conditions here
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: {
              $ifNull: [
                "$transport_details",
                []
              ]
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$transport_details.status",
              -1
            ]
          },
          "Requested"
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$transport_details.status",
              -1
            ]
          },
          "Inactive"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zH4x2OTpfBu)